# HTML lang attribute on xslt in dependency of web site language

Tags: xslt

First - Sorry for my bad English.

I need to add lang attribute to html open tag in dependency which languages are selected on website.
 How it looks now:

```
<xsl:template match="root">
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
                <title>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="Document/@title!=''">
                            <xsl:value-of select="Document/@title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:when test="ContentList/@title!=''">
                            <xsl:value-of select="ContentList/@title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@ContentHeader" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>- <xsl:value-of select="@title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/> - <xsl:value-of select="@slogan" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I try to make this condition

```
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@lang='rus'">
                    <html lang="ru">
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="@lang='rom'">
                    <html lang="ro">
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <html lang="en">
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: And, 'does not work' does not tell me where to start helping you. Do you get 'lang="en"'? Do you get any replacement at all?

Answer (score 0):

The XSLT stylesheet must be a well-formed XML document. That means elements must be properly nested, which your example violates by having three start tags without matching end tags. Think in terms of generating structure, not tags.

Starting from your original stylesheet (which has other issues, but I don't want to quibble about them right now), the easy solution is to make only the attribute conditional:

```
<html>
    <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="@lang='rus'">
          <xsl: attribute name="lang"
               value="ru"/>
       </xsl:when> 
       <xsl:when test="@lang='rom'">
          <xsl: attribute name="lang"
               value="ro"/>
       </xsl:when> 
       <xsl: otherwise>
          <xsl: attribute name="lang"
               value="en"/>
       </xsl: otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

    <!-- etc... -->
```

Comment: "*the easy solution is to make only the attribute conditional*" Actually, it would be easier (and shorter!) to make only the **value** of the attribute conditional.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: feel free to post an answer demonstrating that solution. I felt that this would be clearer to a novice. De gustibus...

Comment: I might do so - after OP posts a reproducible example.

Comment: It work after formating but value not set,
i get <html lang=""> empty value

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @keshlam

This is solution

```
<html>
            <xsl:choose>
               <xsl:when test="@lang='rus'">
                  <xsl:attribute name="lang">ru</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:when> 
               <xsl:when test="@lang='rom'">
                 <xsl:attribute name="lang">ro</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:when> 
               <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:attribute name="lang">en</xsl:attribute>
               </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
```